# Confused about move semantics w/ operator overloading

Tags: c++

I'm confused about C++ move semantics when used with operator overloading.

For example:
(header)

```
#pragma once
#include <vector>
namespace Mat {
    using namespace std;
    template <class T = double>
    class Matrix {
        public: 
        vector<vector<T>> &data;
        size_t Rows;
        size_t Cols;
        // ctor
        Matrix(size_t rows = 1, size_t cols = 1) :
            data(*(new vector<vector<T>>(rows, vector<T>(cols)))) {
            Rows = rows;
            Cols = cols;
            }
        // copy assignment
        Matrix &operator=(const Matrix &m) {
            cout << "Copy =" << endl;
            delete &data;
            Rows = m.Rows;
            Cols = m.Cols;
            data = *(new vector<vector<T>>(m.data));
            return *this;
            }
        // move assignment
        Matrix &operator=(Matrix &&m) {
            cout << "Move =" << endl;
            Rows = m.Rows;
            Cols = m.Cols;
            data = m.data;
            return *this;
            }
        // destructor
        ~Matrix() {
            delete &data;
            }
        // addition
        Matrix &operator+(const Matrix &right) {
            const auto &left = *this;
            auto &result = *(new Matrix<T>(left.Rows, left.Cols));
            for (size_t r = 0; r < Rows; r++) {
                for (size_t c = 0; c < Cols; c++) {
                    result.data[r][c] = left.data[r][c] + right.data[r][c];
                    }
                }
            return result;
            }
        };
    }
```

(main/driver)

```
int _tmain(int argc, _TCHAR* argv []) {
    Mat::Matrix<double> mat1(3,3);
    Mat::Matrix<double> mat2(3, 3);
    std::default_random_engine generator;
    std::uniform_int_distribution<int> distribution(1, 6);
    for (int r = 0; r < 3; r++) {
        for (int c = 0; c < 3; c++) {
            mat1.data[r][c] = distribution(generator);
            mat2.data[r][c] = distribution(generator);
            }
        }
    Mat::Matrix<double> mat3;
    mat3 = mat1 + mat2;
    }
```

When I execute this code. It indicates that "mat3 = mat1 + mat2" is using the copy assignment operator.  I expected (and wanted) it to use the move assignment operator.  I'm using VS2013.

Can someone explain why this is happening and how I can get the desired move semantics?
Thanks

Comment: Oh, my... What is even happening with that `new` and reference? Why can't you just construct a `vector` inside the class?

Comment: Who is teaching you C++? This is absolutely horrible. Just store a `vector<vector<T>>`, not a reference to one. Then erase the code for your assignment operators and your destructor, because the defaults will be implemented correctly. And don't use `new`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `operator+` not only is leaking memory, but is also returning a `Mat::Matrix` *by reference*. Therefore the expression `mat1 + mat2` can only bind to:

```
Matrix &operator=(const Matrix&);
```

What you want to do is to return a `Matrix` by value, instead. Finally, I see you are using `new` all over the place. You don't need dynamic allocation, especially with `std::vector`.

Answer (score 0):

Among a bunch of other issues, your `operator+()` is returning a non-`const` l-value reference, not a temporary r-value ... thus it's going to bind to the `const` l-value reference in the copy assignment operator.